# Shopify - Site says no pages are present

Tags: javascript, html, css, shopify, liquid

My friend got ripped off by some web designers for site design and they left his site in a pretty broken state. I myself am an amateur web designer so I want to fix his site and help him a bit. I've used wordpress and other site builders but never shopify. I have also built a couple of sites from scratch with php, html, css and JS for a few fancy transitions but never liquid - shopify's language. No biggie, I thought, I can pick it up while I try to fix some of the site, but the site seems to have been made in a really strange way.

**The site works but is very buggy and there are probably 15 pages total. The issue is that I can't edit anything.**

For example, on the drag on drop designer there is no content, however the whole site is there on screen. I can interact with it but the drag and drop designer displays no change - usually the sections are on there, but they have been removed.

Despite being a multi-page site with a homepage, about, faq, mission, products and deals pages (amongst a couple of others) none are on shopify. It says there are no pages. This is weird I thought. I cannot edit the HTML code for any of the site because I cannot locate it. I understand liquid has objects and is a bit different to the usual web programming languages, but **I cannot find any text from the site at all** (such as descriptions).

Because there are no pages, I cannot make a menu, however in all of the theme files there are no href links to any other pages. For example, the menu at the top of the page has "Home   About   Products     Deals" and I cannot find one of those words in the code. No problem, I'll edit header.liquid, only that file is empty and contains no content. In the footer I cannot edit anything as the footer is empty too, yet on the site it has code and links to other pages in.

I cannot edit any pages. I cannot find any simple HTML. I would rather not link the site but I will glady answer any questions anyone has. I have studied computer science for 10 years officially, and am very used to practical programming. I have never seen anything like it, and cannot find anything about it online.

Comment: What is the question here? The text can be anywhere, it can be hard-coded, it can come from the translatable strings, it can come from metafields, it can come from sections, it can come from settings_schema or it can come from the page content. Without any code and specific issues it will be hard to provide support. The summary of your question is "I went blindly, too lazy to learn it, tell me where to find it." - which is not ok. Shopify has a rich documentation, it has a FREE partner learning program for theme development - try to learn it. (it's one of the easiest framework languages)

Comment: @drip fair enough. I would argue that this is code related as it liquid is a programming language